# Simple PDO query returns memory-size error

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo, memory-size

I tried to make a simple pdo request to select all values of a table

```
<?php public function query($query) { $this->stmt = $this->query($query); } ?>
```

But when I call it like

```
$db->query('SELECT * FROM teams'); $teams = $db->resultset(); print_r($teams);
```

an error occured

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 65484 bytes) in /var/www/flunky/functions/mysql.class.php on line 29
```

I tried to increase the memory size in php.ini and with `ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');`, but it doesn´t work. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Run this code before running a query

```
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY, false);
```

Further reading [Buffered and Unbuffered queries](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#mysqlnd)

> I tried to increase the memory size in php.ini and with ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');, but it doesn´t work.

It worked, actually.

The error message says that this exact amount were exhausted.

Comment: Next error occured:
'Fatal error: Call to undefined method database::setAttribute() in /var/www/flunky/backend.php on line 38'

I used it with my $db variable

'$db->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY, false);
        $db->query('SELECT * FROM teams');
        $teams = $db->resultset();
        print_r($teams);'

Comment: you tagged your question with PDO, so I provided solution for PDO

Comment: Yeah and it is PDO, or not? why does he called it an "undefined method"?

Comment: because your "database" is anything but PDO

Comment: Shouldn't it be `false` for unbuffered queries? Or how is this going to fix the memmory issue?